# Pony ORM - entity attribute optional on instance create but required on db save

Tags: ponyorm

In Pony ORM entity attribute declared as `Required()` has to be provided when creating an instance. If I declare it as `Optional()` the database field in some cases becomes nullable (integers) which is suboptimal in a scenario where the database is accessed by other applications. Looking at the code I see the validation is skipped if attribute is `auto` or `volatile` but neither option seems to be good choice - `auto` is described as allowed only for autoincrementing primary keys and `volatile` discards value set and refetches it lazily (and makes other assumptions related to optimistic transaction control).

Is there any way in Pony to set field `NOT NULL` in database but otherwise optional when creating entity instance, kind of deferred check?

Comment: I've created a [feature request](https://github.com/ponyorm/pony/issues/573) for this because I too think it would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

In your entity attribute, you need to put a parameter 'nullable=True', this makes the field accept not null values.
Example:

```
    x = Optional(str, nullable=True)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: That's the opposite of what I want - require attribute value at save time but allow it to be empty when creating instance.